# Dealing with an Ok() response from API endpoint

Tags: c#, httpclient, .net-standard-2.0

I'm dealing with an endpoint that someone else wrote a long time ago that the return looks like this:

```
return Ok();
```

On my side, with most of the other endpoints, I know how to deal with the return values.  Like with a boolean return, I'll do this:

```
bool result = httpClient.Post<bool>(this.Uri, request).Result;
```

But with that empty Ok(), I'm not sure how to handle it on my side.  Any hints would be most appreciated.

Comment: What http client are you using?

Comment: Ok means http status code 200, so if its 200 then use the return value

Comment: You're *not* handling the response correctly. There's no `HttpClient.Post<T>`. Is that your own method? At the very least you should `await` it, not block it. [HttpClient.PostAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.postasync?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_Http_HttpClient_PostAsync_System_Uri_System_Net_Http_HttpContent_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) returns an `HttpResponseMessage` with a Status code and the response content. Your method probably checks that status code already and returns the payload if it's OK, otherwise it throws

Comment: It could be Angular's HttpClient, which has that signature.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET Core, an [Ok()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.ok?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_Ok) returns an empty 200 response. You could handle such using the HttpClient:

```
var downloadResult = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
if (downloadResult.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // Handle success
}
```

Comment: I think it's a POST, not a GET

Comment: In that case, simply use PostAsync instead. Same handling if empty response.

Comment: @Julian it doesn't matter, both `HttpClient.PostAsync` and `GetAsync` return an `HttpResponseMessage`. There's no `HttpClient.Post<T>`, this is either the OP's own method or some extension with an unfortunate name. The OP (or the author of the extension method) *already* handles the status code one way or another

Comment: It would make you example a bit better, but sure there isn't a big difference